# ¿Como leer la respuesta arrojada por un API en Angular?

Tags: angular

Lo que pasa es que estoy construyendo un inicio de sesión, cuando el usuario ingresa los datos de forma correcta el servidor responde enviando un JSON con los siguientes datos:

```
{"id":1,"snombres":"dato","spaterno":"dato",...}
```

Lo que no se es como leer ese JSON para almacenarlo en localstorage, ya que esos datos los usare posteriormente, actualmente el código lo tengo así:

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm){
   /*
    codigo de la función

   */
    login.subscribe({
      next: function(data){
        //segmento de código en caso de que el inicio de sesión sea correcto
        window.location.href = '../pages/dashboard';
      },
      error: function(err){
        //segmento de código que manda una alerta en caso de no existir el usuario u otra cosa que tenga que ver con un error
        })
      },
      complete: function(){},      
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear una interfaz con el modelo que esperas recibir y luego crear variables en el localstorage, en caso que falle rediriges al mismo login.

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
   /*
    codigo de la función

   */
    login.subscribe({
      next: function(data:loginModel){
        //segmento de código en caso de que el inicio de sesión sea correcto

        if (data.ok) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.jwtToken);
            localStorage.setItem('usuario', data.name);
            localStorage.setItem('email', data.email);
            localStorage.setItem('id', data.id);
            ...todas las variables que quieras guardar

        }else{
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        window.location.href = '../pages/dashboard';
      },
      error: function(err){
        //segmento de código que manda una alerta en caso de no existir el usuario u otra cosa que tenga que ver con un error

      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

        })
      },
      complete: function(){},      
    })
  }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu problema con ese código?